# Interleaved multi_curl php

Tags: php, curl

Can I do a multi_curl between another multi_curl in php?

What I want to achieve:

1. multi_curl a script P1.
2. multi_curl another script P2.
3. get result for P2.
4. get result for P1.

My requirement is to multi_curl them separately.

My efforts :-

```
$ch_multi1 = curl_multi_init();
$ch_multi2 = curl_multi_init();
$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_URL,"http://URL/to/page1.php");
curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL,"http://URL/to/page2.php");
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_multi_add_handle($ch_multi1,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($ch_multi2,$ch2);

echo "multi_curl_1 ".date("H:i:s")."<br>";
$running1 = NULL;
do
{
    $ret = curl_multi_exec($ch_multi1, $running1);
} while ($ret == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

echo "multi_curl_2 ".date("H:i:s")."<br>";
do
{
    curl_multi_exec ($ch_multi2, $running2);
}
while ( $running2 > 0 );

echo "result_2 ".date("H:i:s")."<br>";
$result =  curl_multi_getcontent($ch2);
echo $result."<br>";

do
{
    curl_multi_exec ($ch_multi1, $running1);
}
while ( $running1 > 0 );

echo "result_1 ".date("H:i:s")."<br>";
$result = curl_multi_getcontent($ch1);
echo $result."<br>";

curl_multi_remove_handle($ch_multi1, $ch1);
curl_multi_remove_handle($ch_multi2, $ch2);
curl_close($ch1);
curl_close($ch2);
```

I have explicitly introduced a delay of 5sec in P1 and 10sec in P2. And It takes 15 secs Instead of 10 secs.

Comment: Please show your effort first. Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

The `curl_multi_init()` command in PHP is **asynchronous**. This means that you should not depend on the output of this function if you are programming a synchronous function.

If you depend on the order of execution in your script, you should use a **synchronous** function, such as executing multiple cURLs in order, or using a callback function.